# How to hide the uibarbutton item of a navigation bar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, show-hide

i am unzipping a file on background thread and i am calling  HomeViewController on main thread.in this view controller i have a  UIBarButtonItem on UINavigationBar.
if i click this button it goes to StoryViewController and the unzipped data is used there. so  i want to show the Home view Controller though the unzipping process is not completed, for that i have to hide the button on the navigation bar when the unzipping starts on backround thread and after completion of the upzipping again i have to show the button on navigation bar. i am calling the methods of homeViewController to hide and show..
What i have to write in those methods..? i mean how to hide and show the uiBarButtonItem on UINavigationBar....?

Thanks....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216259/how-to-add-bar-button-to-uinavigationbar-in-iphone

Comment: Try not to put the same question twice and create duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to add bar button to uinavigationbar in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216259/how-to-add-bar-button-to-uinavigationbar-in-iphone)

here is the answer..

Answer (score 18):

Once you have created your UIBarButtonItem say "myButton", you can add/remove it to your navigation controller using in your view Controller:

```
if(show)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myButton;
else
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: i added barbuttonitem to a navigation bar through IB  should i add it programatically

Comment: in your case, I don't see any reason to build it via IB. you can do it programmatically very easily using :    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target: action:

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *addButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Start" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self  action:@selector(tourBtnClicked:)];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton1;                                                     added this code in viewDidLoad method but its not working no button added should i add navigationbar also programmatically..?

Comment: Self.navigationItem will work only if your viewController is in a navigationController.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216259/how-to-add-bar-button-to-uinavigationbar-in-iphone  this is the solution

Comment: if you use IB, you can make it STRONG instead of WEAK to keep it in memory. That worked for me :)