# How to add bar button to uinavigationbar in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

My class is a normal view controller and I added a navigation bar through IB and i am adding a barbutton item on left to the navigation bar programmatically using the following code

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Start" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self  action:@selector(tourBtnClicked:)];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton1;
```

but its not working... should i add the navigationbar also programmatically or should my class a uinavigationcontroller

Thank u

Comment: Where did you place this piece of code?

Comment: i tried in both viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using a `UINavigationController`, you will need to add code to manage the navigation bar programmatically. For example, you'd need to send a message to the navigation bar to push a navigation item onto its stack using the following method:

```
- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You should also make sure the the `navigationItem` property isn't currently `nil` when you attempt to set its properties. From the `UIViewController` class reference for the `navigationItem` property:

> To ensure the navigation item is
>   configured, you can override this
>   property and add code to load the bar
>   button items there or load the items
>   in your view controller’s
>   initialization code

Comment: Thanks jlehr for ur quick response   UIBarButtonItem *addButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Start" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self  action:@selector(tourBtnClicked:)];
 
 UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil];
 navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton1;
 [self.navBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:YES];

Comment: added in viewDidLoad and its working but i am getting the right barbuttonitem also with the title i have on navBar. if i used left button in the code its working fine. how to solve it?.. thanks again..

Comment: ok..can u tell me how to disable the barButtonItem which is added through IB, if its not possible how to disable that which is added through programmatically

Comment: jlehr..!! its working.. wt i did is, deleted the navigationitem under the uinavigationbar in the interface builder. and its worked with above code.. thanks...!! but do u know how to disable or disappear the uibarbuttonitem from navigationbar..?

Comment: Ok, I have the same issue but can not make it work, could u please place proper answer how to do it? thanks

Comment: Ok, figured this out, still -1 to jlehr for obscure answer and +1 to rockey as he(she?) answered the question. p.s. I think you need to release your addButton1 afterwards:)